# What is this notation in JS, can someone please explain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across this function, called generateMessage which takes 2 parameters and returns and object. The function is as follows:

```
var generateMessage = (from, text)=>{
    return {
        from,
         text,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime()
    }
};

module.exports = {generateMessage};
```

This does **NOT** throw any errors, and attaches 3 properties to the returned object: '.from' , '.text' and '.createdAt', I am confused about the '.from' and '.text' properties.

My question is why don't we write `from: from` , `text:text`, in this way the returned object will have a proto property of .from and .text, which will have their values as the `from` and `text` from the parameters.

Why does just writing `from` and `text` for the returned object work in this case?

Comment: you can write `from:from` and `text: text` - it's a stylistic choice. It's syntactic sugar, much like the fat arrow function (`=>`)

Comment: it is a short hand notation, if your variable is named from and the property is named form you can write `from` instead of  `from: from` it will have the same effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's ECMAScript's 'shorthand''s property and notation:

http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand

http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation

It's as the name suggests, a shorthand method of object definition.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to JS and was confused by notation.